# How to set checkbox value to checked in zend framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I am wondering how to set the checkbox value of a zend form element to 'checked'?
I went in my Debug-11-condition so I would expect to see an active arrow in my box. Unfortunately the box remains empty.

```
$room = $this->getRoomTable()->getRoom($roomId);
$roomForm->bind($room);
$lightOneValue = $room->getLighsone();
if ($lightOneValue == "100"){
    Debug::dump('11');
    $roomForm->get('lightone')->setChecked(true);
} else { ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change true as 1 dude,

```
   $roomForm->get('lightone')->setValue(1);
```

Comment: Thanks Nanda, anyway - there is no difference. If I place both methods in my code, so setChecked(true) and setValue(true) I can see, that the method runs through the right snippet of code, the value attribute in the HTML-code is correct, but the  attribute checked=true is missing!

Comment: Change true as 1 dude,

   $roomForm->get('lightone')->setValue(1);

Comment: can u post the checkbox form code? What u have mention the checked value in form

Comment: Okay I think I got the problem solved - in my view file I used $this->formInput($form->get('myelementname')) and so the elements did not match - maybe that was the reason. Anyway I changed to whole procedure to use radio buttons and now it is working.

Comment: You should also user formCheckbox as ViewHelper. formInput did not work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

$this->formCheckbox instead of $this->formInput was the point in my case, as Nykac pointed out above.